# twitteR, "Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates", ubuntu 12.04, R 3.1.0,

Tags: r, twitter

```
> install_github("twitteR", username="geoffjentry")
Installing github repo twitteR/master from geoffjentry
Downloading master.zip from https://github.com/geoffjentry/twitteR/archive/master.zip
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates
> 
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

Comment: That means whatever cert is being used by the repo site doesn't have its registrar listed in your system's master CA list. e.g. the cert was signed by "XYZ corp", and xyz corp's cert isn't in your CA list, so there's no way to validate that it's a properly issued cert.

Comment: Thanks for response. how to add it into list?