# R Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates, Windows

Tags: r, ssl, curl, ca, r-googlesheets

When trying to import a google sheet using the `gs_read()` function, I get the following error message:

> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :    Peer
>   certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates

I am following this [vignette](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jennybc/googlesheets/master/vignettes/basic-usage.html) and get the error when using the code:

```
oceania <- gap %>%  gs_read(ws = "Oceania")
```

I have found similar issues for [Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23435232/twitter-peer-certificate-cannot-be-authenticated-with-given-ca-certificates) and [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15135834/php-curl-curlopt-ssl-verifypeer-ignored), but nothing that has been able to help me.

Does anyone know why I am getting this error and how to fix it?

I am using R 3.3.2 and Windows 7.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

My colleague had the same issue and I stumbled on [this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/fixing-peer-certificate-cannot-be-authenticated/) post on R-Bloggers by Andrew Collier. The solution below will fix your problem, but I don't know if it might cause other security issues.

```
library(httr)
set_config(config(ssl_verifypeer = 0L))
```

update: This will disable ssl verification. https://github.com/r-lib/httr/issues/262